# C++ getline() function malfunctioning for inputs with no whitespaces

Tags: c++, buffer, cin, getline

Here is a code in which I've been facing difficulties lately-

```
int main(){

ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(NULL);
int n,k;
cin >> n >> k;
cin.ignore();
int arr[n];
fill_n(arr , n, 0);
int brr[n];
fill_n(brr , n, 1);
for(int i=1;i<=k;i++){ //Loop 1
    char str[8];
    cin.getline(str,9);
    if(str=="CLOSEALL") //block 1
        memset(arr , 0, n * sizeof(arr[0]));
    else{
        arr[str[6]-'0'-1]=1*brr[str[6]-'0'-1];
        if(brr[str[6]-'0'-1]==0)
            brr[str[6]-'0'-1]=1;
        else
            brr[str[6]-'0'-1]=0;
            }
    int c=0;
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        if(arr[j]==1)
        c++;
    }

    cout << c << endl;
}
```

The problem I've been facing is with the input. According to the question, the input commands can be `CLICK N`, where **N** is an integer, or `CLOSEALL` (note the exact case and number of whitespaces). Whenever I work with an input of `CLICK N`, the program runs fine, but as soon as I input `CLOSEALL`, it doesn't execute the **block 1**(mentioned in the code) and the program terminates immediately, even if **Loop 1**(mentioned in the code) has to go on till the input value of `k`. I assume that it's some problem related to the `getline()` buffer, as `CLOSEALL` doesn't have any whitespace and is malfunctioning, while `CLICK N` has a whitespace and isn't malfunctioning. Can someone suggest how to correct this flush discrepancy, so that the code works perfectly?

> PS: I haven't included the question, as I believe it's of no use here. Also, I've included the packages in my code as required. If someone needs the question, I would edit my post.

Comment: Whatever website you are using, it's not doing a good job at teaching. I suggest getting [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn from. `char[8]` can only store 7 characters, because it needs space for null terminator. `str=="CLOSEALL"` does not do any useful comparison, it will always be `false`. `int arr[n];` is a Variable Length Array and only some compilers support it as extension to C++.

Comment: I'm using VSCODE, it does give true on comparison with `CLOSEALL`, I've tried that out.

Comment: There is no way in which comparison with `==` of local `char[]` to string literal can produce `true`. It does pointer comparison, and these pointers must be pointing to different memory areas. And even if it did, it has different semantics, for example `"asdf" == "asdfghjk"` could produce `true`. For comparison of C-style strings there exists [`std::strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp), or, if you used C++ `std::string` instead of `char[]` you can use `==` and it will correctly compare.

Comment: Right. Previously I had worked with string, and it had worked, but then I needed getline to input the stream. Realized it now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

you can try `std::stringstream`

```cpp
// swapping ostringstream objects
#include <string>       // std::string
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <sstream>      // std::stringstream

int main () {
  std::string str;
  std::cin >> str;
  std::stringstream ss;

  ss << str;

  int foo,bar;
  ss >> foo >> bar;

  std::cout << "foo: " << foo << '\n';
  std::cout << "bar: " << bar << '\n';

  return 0;
}
// in: 
// 100 200
// out: 
// foo: 100
// bar: 200
```